# Getting rid of Conditions when blessed

Tags: eldritch-horror

To get rid of a negative condition, you have to role a 5 or a 6.  If you are blessed, where 4 count as successes, does the condition disappears on a 4, 5, and 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first unwritten rule of cooperative games is *if a rule can be interpreted in several ways, the right one is the least helpful to the players*.  Therefore conditions only disapear on a 5 or 6 regardless of other effects.

This is the answer from the [official FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/eldritch-horror/support/EH01%20Errata%20&%20FAQ%202013-12-20.pdf):

> **Q**. Is every roll considered a test?
>
> **A**. No. An effect that tells you to
>   roll a specific number of dice, such as the flare effect on a Cursed
>   Condition, is not a test. These rolls cannot be re rolled or modified
>   by effects that affect tests.